# How to remove an object from array based on key: value pair?

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have this array of objects:

```
[{name: "John", age: "30"},
 {name: "Jane", age: "20"}]
```

Can I remove an object from that array based on a key value pair? For example remove object with name: "John"?

Comment: You can use javascript to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can splice the object containing the name "John"

```js
var a=[{name: "John", age: "30"},
 {name: "Jane", age: "20"}];
 a.forEach((e)=>{
 if(e.name=="John")
 a.splice(a.indexOf(e),1)
 })
 console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `reject`:

```
var people = [{name: "John", age: "30"},
 {name: "Jane", age: "20"}]
people = people.reject(person => person.name === "John")
```